# How to do an Android App run on a particular screen size and on Particular OS..?

Tags: android, screen-size, android-screen, android-screen-support

Like I am making an app that has to target for a particular screen size and for particular OS,and I want that if the device don't have that particular screen size and OS thn this app should not even get started....?

How to do that...?

Any help would be highly appreciable..

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to filter your application from market according to screen size ans OS version is

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="false" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

when i give small screen false, and published in market, the app will not even displayed in small screen device market.